# Rails: why isn't this marked_for_destruction not destroyed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-activerecord

** update **
it all seems to be related to a custom validator: if I remove it, it works as expected. see code at the end
**

I have a model `budget` that has many `multi_year_impacts`

in the console, if I run:

```
b = Budget.find(4)
b.multi_year_impacts.size #=> 2
b.update_attributes({multi_year_impacts_attributes: {id: 20, _destroy: true} } ) #=> true
b.multi_year_impacts.size #=> 1 (so far so good)
b.reload
b.multi_year_impacts.size #=> 2 What???
```

and if before `b.reload` I do `b.save` (which shouldn't be needed anyway), it's the same.

**Any idea why my child record doesn't get destroyed?**

Some additional information, just in case:

Rails 3.2.12

in `budget.rb`

```
attr_accessible :multi_year_impacts_attributes
has_many :multi_year_impacts, as: :impactable, :dependent => :destroy
accepts_nested_attributes_for :multi_year_impacts, :allow_destroy => true
validates_with MultiYearImpactValidator # problem seems to com from here
```

in `multi_year_impact.rb`

```
belongs_to :impactable, polymorphic: true
```

in `multi_year_impact_validator.rb`

```
class MultiYearImpactValidator < ActiveModel::Validator
  def validate(record)
    return false unless record.amount_before && record.amount_after && record.savings        
    lines = record.multi_year_impacts.delete_if{|x| x.marked_for_destruction?}

    %w[amount_before amount_after savings].each do |val|
      if lines.inject(0){|s,e| s + e.send(val).to_f} != record.send(val)
        record.errors.add(val.to_sym, " please check \"Repartition per year\" below: the sum of all lines must be equal of total amounts")
      end
    end

  end
end
```

Comment: not really sure if it matters but can you try `multi_year_impacts_attributes: [{id: 20, _destroy: true}]` (wrap it in an array)?

Comment: nope :( still doesn't work
Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: what if you do `update_attributes!`

Comment: Clearly caching... try b2=Budget.find(4) and b2.multi_year_impacts.size to confirm.

Comment: I also thought about that...
but stil the same :(
`b2.multi_year_impacts.size #=>2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it looks like the culprit was here

```
if lines.inject(0){|s,e| s + e.send(val).to_f} != record.send(val)
    record.errors.add(val.to_sym, " please check \"Repartition per year\" below: the sum of all lines must be equal of total amounts")
end
```

changing this to the slightly more complex

```
  total = 0
  lines.each do |l|
    total += l.send(val).to_f unless l.marked_for_destruction?
  end
  if total != record.send(val)
    record.errors[:amount_before] << " please check \"Repartition per year\" below: the sum of all lines must be equal of total amounts"
  end
```

solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

it might depend on your rails version, however, comparing your code to the current [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html):

> Now, when you add the _destroy key to the attributes hash, with a
>   value that evaluates to true, you will destroy the associated model:
>
> ```
> member.avatar_attributes = { :id => '2', :_destroy => '1' }
> member.avatar.marked_for_destruction? # => true 
> member.save
> member.reload.avatar # => nil
> ```
>
> Note that the model will not be destroyed until the parent is saved.

you could try with:

```
b.multi_year_impacts_attributes =  {id: 20, _destroy: true}
b.save
```

Comment: Thanks (I had seen the rails doc) but still no luck :(